# I will set up a call on next Thursday - acceptable? Or "for"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions

I am not sure whether the "on" preposition is correct in this case, and whether the sentence itself makes sense: can't it be interpreted that I will set up the call next Thursday (when actually I want to set up the call to take place on next Thursday?)

Comment: Just because something is ambiguous, it doesn't mean that it's wrong.

Comment: I don't know why, but *my* version of English doesn't allow ***on*** to be used before a day in the future at the same time as a "determiner" such as ***this*** or ***next***. So for me the options are *I'll go **on** Monday, I'll go **this** Monday* or *I'll go **next** Monday*. I (personally?) *can't* say *I'll go **on next** Monday*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So you say "I will set up a call next Thursday"? Or "for next Thursday"?

Comment: I can certainly say both of those things. Where *I will set up a call next Thursday* means the act of setting up the call won't take place until that day (and *feasibly*, what I might be setting up is a call that will actually *take place* next *Friday* or later). But *I will set up a call **for** next Thursday* definitely means the call will take place on that day (I'll probably set it up right now, but maybe I won't get around to that for a few days; the key point is I'll definitely have made arrangements for the call *before* it takes place next Thursday).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your two comments make a good answer. Please don't answer in comments!

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I specifically referred to ***my*** version of English. I've no good reason for supposing everyone else thinks the same, and I've no idea whether there's some definable syntactic principle involved. I'm pretty sure of my ground for the *second* comment, but I'm not convinced that's a complete answer to the actual Question (as opposed to being a valid respone to a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of English doesn't allow ***on*** to be used before a day in the future at the same time as a "determiner" such as ***this*** or ***next***. So for me the options are..,

> *I'll go **on** Monday*
> *I'll go **this** Monday*
> *I'll go **next** Monday*
> ...I (personally?) *can't* say...
> *I'll go **on next** Monday*  <=== NOT VALID FOR ME!

---

> *I will set up a call next Thursday*
> means the act of setting up the call won't take place until that day - and feasibly, what I might be setting up is a call that will actually take place next Friday or later.

> *I will set up a call **for** next Thursday*
> means the call *will* take place on that day. I'll probably set it up right now, but maybe I won't get around to that for a few days; the key point is I'll definitely have made arrangements for the call before it takes place next Thursday.